# Matlab2Tikz colorbar / colormap issues

Tags: matlab2tikz

I've got some issues using the matlab2tikz script by Nico Schlömer.
In Matlab I created a 3d plot including a bunch of patches. Some scalar values are highlighted using the jet colormap (see the attached *.png file).

[image: Matlab figure]

I then translated this figure into a tikzpicture by invoking matlab2tikz('Test6.tex'). Matlab printed the information

```
> Found colormap/jet to be a pretty good match for your color map (||diff||=0.0280337).
```

Compiling the rather huge tikz file by

```
\usetikzlibrary{external} \tikzset{external/system call={lualatex
    \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
    -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=autofigs/]
```

and

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\input{Bilder/Test6.tex}%
\caption{\label{fig:1}Our figure}
\end{figure}
```

using pdflatex produces this results (screenshot of corresponding pdf)

[[image: Resulting output[2]]

Both, the colormap and the colorbar are obviously completely different to the original plot. 
Can anyone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: Judging by your description and the answer below, this sounds very much like `matlab2tikz` doing the wrong thing, and that is something that should be reported at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues if you haven't already. Bug reports like that are off-topic here. It would also be great if you could give some feedback to Jonas, whether his answer helped or not. (Leave a comment and/or upvote/accept.)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I think there is an error in the generation of the colormap in the matlab2tikz.m file. You will have to change some things in your Test6.tex file:

In your tex file there should be the following lines:

```
point meta min=...,
point meta max=...,
```

With on the dots your values. This limits the colours of your colormap. These two lines needs to be removed. After doing this already a plot should be generated with the right color values but the colorbar definition will still wrong in order to fix this, the next code block

```
colormap={mymap}{[1pt] ...}
```

needs to be placed after

```
colormap={patchmap}{[1pt] ...}
```

This will fix the colorbar. But still the tickvalues of the colorbar will be off. This can be fixed manually by using:

```
colorbar style={        
    ytick={...},
    yticklabels={...}
    }
```

If it is not completely clear I can make the changes in your file.